# TWRP, can't uncheck "Mount system partition read-only"

Tags: samsung, twrp, lineageos, magisk

I installed this [Twrp](https://forum.xda-developers.com/samsung-a-series/orig-development/recovery-twrp-galaxy-a40-t4025587) on my Samsung a40 using Heimdall, worked well but I can't uncheck the option "Mount system partition read-only" in Mount. So, I can't flash Magisk, it fails to mount /system. I get the following error "unable to find partition for path /system" when I try to write to the /system. Any ideas, how I can fix it ?

Comment: try `mount -r /system_root` from twrp terminal. magisk error is most likely not related to read-only problem because it is systemless root method. unable to find partition error is maybe caused by wrong recovery.fstab. claim it to TWRP maintainer or unpack twrp.img and fix yourself. in twrp terminal, type `ls -1 $(find /dev/block -name by-name)/*` use this paths for /etc/recovery.fstab (or twrp.fstab if exist)